# Is it better to run Sonar in Java EE Server like tomcat or standalone?

Tags: tomcat, sonarqube

Using it for production environment, 
I didn't see any recommendation on their website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most operational teams will tell you that it's best to use an independant Web server like Tomcat, because it's easier for them to administrate the server (most of the time because they have the knowledge).

However, Jetty (which is embedded in the standalone version) is a "real" web server as well, and lost of people could tell you that Jetty is robust enough and that Sonar runs well in this mode.

So actually, you should let your operational team choose, for in the end they are the ones who will handle the Sonar infrastructure.